# Mistakenly upgraded MongoDB 2.6 straight to 3.2

Tags: mongodb

I upgraded a dev box form mongo 2.6 to 3.2. I had every intention of upgrading to 3.0 and then 3.2 as per the docs, but thanks to a glorious bit of lack of attention ended up just upgrading straight to 3.2.

Strangely, things seem to be working.

I have no intention of making this mistake on production boxes, but I would like to know if I should do something on the upgraded dev box to avoid issues in the future.

Does anyone know what the possible issues might be?

Thanks!

Comment: What sort of deployment did you upgrade, and what was your specific version of MongoDB 2.6.x? If you upgraded a standalone 2.6 server without authentication you might be OK (although this is not a tested upgrade path). Any more complex configuration (auth enabled, replica set, or sharded cluster) is likely to run into compatibility issues if you skip major version upgrade steps. Upgrade steps between major versions typically include updating authentication, oplog, and/or config server metadata so you definitely don't want to skip intermediate upgrades for a production deployment.

Comment: @stennie yeah, definitely plan to follow all steps for all production severs. This mistake was on a dev server, so not a huge issue, just wondering whether I should take the time to blow the server away and recreate, which takes a while as the server spin up includes a dump restore that takes almost a day.

Comment: You didn't confirm whether your dev server was a standalone without auth, which is a case where I can't think of any obvious errors in skipping 3.0 in the upgrade path to 3.2. If you have a more complex configuration (existing authentication data, replica set, or sharded cluster) you should follow the proper upgrade path as you will run into issues due to unexpected schema/metadata. The issues will likely manifest as invariant failures or assertions, so you could also check the logs on your dev server to see if anything appears to be amiss.

Comment: @Stennie the server had auth (though with a compatible auth schema), and was a single node in a replica set. Though I didn't notice any issues immediately, I decided to reinstall 2.6 and just do it right. Thanks for your input!